# $\lim_{y \rightarrow^{nt}x}\int \omega(y-z)g(z) \,d\sigma(z)=\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\int_{|x-z|>\epsilon}\omega_j(x-z)g(z)\,d\sigma(z)$

Tags: integration, measure-theory

We need to show

$\lim_{y \rightarrow^{nt}x}\int \omega_j(y-z)g(z) \,d\sigma(z)=\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\int_{|x-z|>\epsilon}\omega_j(x-z)g(z)\,d\sigma(z)$

Here is the necessary information :

$\Sigma$ is the boundary of Bounded lipchitz domain, in $\mathbb R^3$. $\sigma$ is the 2-dimensional (surface) measure on $\Sigma$, the variable $y$ always belong to $\Omega$ or $\Omega^c$ but never to the boundary $\Sigma$

We are working on $L^2(\mu)^4$ and $L^2(\sigma)^4$,

so $g\in L^2(\sigma)^4$ and $\omega_j$s are $4\times 4$ matrix functions of $x$.

1. $y\rightarrow^{nt}x$ means y approach x "non-tangentially". It is vague to me too.
2. $\omega_1(x)=\frac{e^{-m|x|}}{4\pi|x|}m\left(\beta+i\alpha.\frac{x}{|x|}\right)$ and $\omega_2(x)=\frac{e^{-m|x|}-1}{4\pi}i\left(\alpha.\frac{x}{|x|^3}\right)$,

$\alpha.x$ can be seen as $\alpha_1 x_1 +\alpha_2 x_2 + \alpha_3 x_3$ where each $\alpha_i$ is $4\times 4$ matrix. And $\beta $ is also a $4\times 4$ matrix.

And see that $\omega_j$ becomes a $4\times 4$ matrix operating in $g(z)$ which is a $4\times 1$ vector.

The following information may be useful :
all the entries of $\omega_j$s are of order $O(|x|^{-1})$. $\sigma $ is a 2 dimensional measure.
Author suggest the use of boundedness of $\Sigma$, generalized Young's inequality, and Dominated convergence theorem.

I am sorry for such a complicated problem, but for the author it is trivial.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to prove for scalar functions $w_j, g$. We assume $g$ is continuous.

We define $v(x)=\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\int_{|x-z|>\epsilon}w_j(x-z)g(z)\,d\sigma(z)$, which is nothing but the right hand side of the identity we're going to prove. Some observations are in order.

1. $g\in L^2(\Sigma)$ and $\Sigma$ is bounded, so $g\in L^1(\Sigma)$.
2. $v(x)$ is well-defined in $\mathbb{R}^3$, that is,  the limit exists as $\epsilon$ goes to $0$. Obviously this is true if $x$ is not on the boundary. This is also true if $x\in \Sigma$ because $w_j(x)=O(|x|^{-1})$, whence the singularity in the integrand is **weak**, which in this case means that $|w_j(x)||x|^2\to 0$  as $|x|\to 0$. This is easy to see for $w_1$, and for $w_2$, we see from Taylor expansion that $e^{-m|x|}-1=-m|x|+O(|x|^2)$, implying $w_2(x)=O(|x|^{-1})$.  Hence $w_j\in L^1(\Sigma).$ This and the fact that $g\in C(\Sigma)$ tell us the limiting integral exist in pointwise sense.

For notational convenience , let me write $v(x)=\int w_j(x-z)g(z)\,d\sigma(z)$.

Hence it comes down to prove that $v(x)$ is continuous up to boundary, non-tangentially, in the sense that for $x\in \Sigma,$ $\lim_{h\to 0}v(x+h\textbf{$\xi$})=v(x)$, where $\textbf{$\xi$}$ is any vector that is not parallel to the tangent plane at point $x$ on $\Sigma.$

To prove this kind of continuity involving an integral is an easy exercise and the approach is commonly seen, for example, in the Dirichlet problem for Laplace equation or initial value problem for heat equation.

Fix $x\in \Sigma,$ $\forall \tau>0$, we split the domain of integration into two parts, near $x$: $|z-x|<\delta$ and away from $x$: $|z-x|>=\delta$, where $\delta$ will be determined later. 
Then we have 
$$v(y)-v(x)=\int_{|z-x|<\delta}w_j(y-z)g(z)-w_j(x-z)g(z)d\sigma(z)+
\int_{|z-x|>\delta}\left(w_j(y-z)-w_j(x-z)\right)g(z)d\sigma(z)=I_1+I_2.$$

For $|I_1|$, since $w_j\in L^1$ and $g$ is bounded, $|I_1|$ can be made as small as possible by choosing a small $\delta$ for all $y$ in a small neighborhood of  $x$.
We choose $\delta$ s.t. $|I_1|<\tau$.

For $|I_2|$, when $y$ is close to $x$, say, $|x-y|<\delta/2$, then we have $|y-z| > |x-z|-|x-y|>\delta/2$, thus $w_j(y-z)$ is uniformly continuous(independent of z, where $|z-x|>\delta$) since we are a distance away from the singularity. Let $y$ approach $x$ s.t. $|w_j(y-z)-w_j(x-z)|<\tau$. Then we have $|I_2|<\tau ||g||_{L^1}$.

Thus we conclude that for any $\tau>0$, we can choose $|y-x|$ sufficiently small so that $|x-y|<\delta/2$ and $|w_j(y-z)-w_j(x-z)|<\tau$.
 Hence $|v(y)-v(x)|< (1+||g||_{L^1})\tau$.

If $w_j, g$ are matrices or vectors, it result follows immediately since what we have proved above implies that for each entry in the matrix, the result holds. Thus it is true for a matrix.

If $g\in L^2(\Sigma)$, since $w_j\in L^1(\Sigma)$, from Minkowski's inequality, $v\in L^2(\Sigma)$, but I'm not sure if the pointwise existence of $v(x)$ on $\Sigma$ still holds. That is, whether 
$w_j(x-z)g(z)\in L^1(d\sigma(z)).$
Nevertheless, the estimate for $|I_2|$ is still valid but I did not see how to bound $|I_1|$. I believe even if we compute the difference $w_j(y-z)-w_j(x-z)$, we may end up with something like $|x-y||y-z|^{-2}$ when $y$ is close to $x$, so it is still hard to find an upper bound for $|I_1|$ or even prove the integrand is in $L^1$.

Comment: sorry, I shall try to work on your solution before the bounty expires. Else expect equivalent bounty someday in future, as a surprise. Thanks for answer

Comment: I think the boundedness of $\Sigma $ may help us to conclude $w_j(x-z)g(z)\in L^1(d\sigma(z)).$. Thanks for the answer though